# Mysql query with 3 tables with one dynamic column (i18n)

Tags: mysql, sql, internationalization

For a multilingual project, I need to write a MySQL query with 3 different tables.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT i.i18n_id, i.name,
(select tx_translation from i18n_translation where id_locale= 'fr_be' 
and id_translation=i.i18n_id) as 'fr_be',
(select tx_translation from i18n_translation where id_locale= 'nl_be' and id_translation=i.i18n_id) as 'nl_be',
(select tx_translation from i18n_translation where id_locale= 'en_gb' and id_translation=i.i18n_id) as 'en_gb'
FROM i18n i
left join i18n_translation itrans on itrans.id_translation=i.i18n_id
group by i18n_id
```

The results are OK but I think `subselects` isn't the best way to get it.

Also, I have one table that holds the languages code, "`i18n_language`" with the following columns (`id, code, name, active`). Like "1,fr_be,Français,1".

How can I write a query without `subselects` and to add the languages code found in `i18n_language` automatically? (so with hard code it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select i.i18n_id, i.name,
       max(case when id_locale = 'fr_be' then tx_translation end) as fr_be,
       max(case when id_locale = 'nl_be' then tx_translation end) as nl_be,
       max(case when id_locale = 'en_gb' then tx_translation end) as en_gb
from i18n i left join
     i18n_translation itrans
     on itrans.id_translation = i.i18n_id
group by i.i18n_id, i.name;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thanks, it works perfectly but what about the i18n_language table that holds the language list ?

Comment: @lio . . . Is that in your question?

Comment: Question is : How can I automatically add the language names (found in i18n_language  table) as a column without hardcode them? I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: @lio . . . That is an entirely different question.  Before asking another question, google "MySQL dynamic pivot".